Can one use managed identity to connect to Azure Postgresql without needing custom code to get token (Like SQL Server)?
Am deploying a blazor app in Azure, connecting to Postgresql in Azure. Current setup, developers connect to dev instance postgresql (On prem or local install) using connectionstring (with UID & password) in appsettings.json. Once deployed to Azure, connectionstring gets overwritten by Web App connectionstring configuration in Azure, and has UID and password for Azure Postgresql DB. For better security, I am looking into using managed identity to move away from storing password anywhere in Azure. Reading this article (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/single-server/how-to-connect-with-managed-identity) fits the requirement, but some token access code is needed. Just wondering if it is possible to keep DB connection code standard across and just change connection strings (I believe that would be possible with SQL Server using "Authentication=Active Directory Default" & Managed Identity in Azure). So two questions,

Anyway to not have the custom code for managed identity for Postgresql, similar to SQL Server using "Authentication=Active Directory Default"?

If 1 is not possible, then we can of course implement the token code. Could those custom code work for connecting to postgresql that is not on Azure? (e.g. on-prem on just on a developer's laptop)? Just trying to see if we can avoid writing code to check for environment and running different DB connection code if possible.


Hope that makes sense?

DefaultAzureCredential can search for a number of different credentials. VS / VS Code / Azure Cli / [User] Managed Identity ... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.identity.defaultazurecredential?view=azure-dotnet#definition So you can manage local access using one of those.

That wont work if it is not on azure. arc enabled server should work as well but local dev stuff wont work

Thanks, yeah I believe the DefaultAzureCredential is what the Microsoft suggest we use in the article I saw, which as Thomas mentioned, will probably fail in our dev environment (Haven't tried though). Not arc enabled servers unfortunately. Anyway, will implement some simple code checking then to call the token access if needed. Thanks.
